# Subclassed NSManagedObject doesn't give designated initialzer Swift

Tags: ios, core-data, swift, subclass, nsmanagedobject

I have a NSManagedObject subclass that I generated using the editor menu >> Create NSManagedObject Subclass...

It inherits everything and it looks like this:
import Foundation
import CoreData

```
class Person: NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var firstname: String
    @NSManaged var lastname: String
}
```

But, when I try to create an instance from my Person class I don't get code hinting `entity: entityDescripition, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext` for the designated initializer, when I ignore it and use it anyway this is what I get:

> CoreData: warning: Unable to load class named 'Person' for entity 'Person'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.

But I have the Person class in my project, it is in my compile source in my build phases, the same thing in Objective C works immediately though..

Any thoughts?

Comment: @MichalCiuba agreed but adding my project name prefix to the entity class doesn't fix it for me, updated it to Foo.Person, also adding the @objc(Person) doesn't give me the proper code hinting or gets rid of the error...

Comment: @thomasdegry: consider documenting what you've done to fix the issue, and link to questions with failed solutions.